# Is it bad to reapply all event listeners when state changes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a hook that lets me change the page in my React app, using the scroll wheel or the `keyup` event. At the end, I came to this solution, which works:

```
function useScrollingPage (pages) {
    const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
    const wheelHandler = (event) => {
        // some logic
        setPage(page + 1);
    };
    useEffect(
        () => {
            window.addEventListener(EVENTS.WHEEL, wheelHandler);
            window.addEventListener(EVENTS.KEY_UP, keyHandler);

            return () => {
                window.removeEventListener(EVENTS.WHEEL, wheelHandler);
                window.removeEventListener(EVENTS.KEY_UP, keyHandler);
            };
        },
        [page],
    );

    return page;
}
```

But, while working on it, I ran into a few iterations.

1. I would call `addEventListener` outside the `useEffect`. This way, everything works, but the listener is never removed.
2. I would pass an empty array as the second argument of `useEffect`. That way, it only runs on component mount, but it doesn't change the `page` reference in `wheelHandler`, so it will always try to set the page to 1 (`setPage(0 + 1)`)
3. Run useEffect every time the `page` changes. It works, but it doesn't feel right to remove and add all listeners every time the state changes.

Is it bad for performance, to add/remove event listeners every time the state changes? What would be the best solution for a problem like this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, when the listeners depends on state or props to subscribe you would want to make use of the above pattern, However in the above case you could do with the callback pattern of state updates and pass an empty array as the second argument of `useEffect`

```
function useScrollingPage (pages) {
    const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
    const wheelHandler = (event) => {
        // some logic
        setPage(page => page + 1);
    };
    useEffect(
        () => {
            window.addEventListener(EVENTS.WHEEL, wheelHandler);
            window.addEventListener(EVENTS.KEY_UP, keyHandler);

            return () => {
                window.removeEventListener(EVENTS.WHEEL, wheelHandler);
                window.removeEventListener(EVENTS.KEY_UP, keyHandler);
            };
        },
        [],
    );

    return page;
}
```

However when you write the above logic, make sure that you aren't using state in the wheelHandler. If you are, then you would follow the pattern that works for you and is recommended.